# What does "conceive" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context:

"The Consultant acknowledges that he will receive or ***conceive*** confidential information pertaining to the activities, operations and business, past, present 
and future, of the Company or its subsidiaries or related or associated companies, which information is not in the public domain."

I cannot understand what it does mean in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked up possible meanings of *conceive* in a dictionary? Obviously, it doesn't mean "to conceive a child."

Comment: Certainly, but the meanings seem not to make sense in this case. Btw, I think that the explanation below by SGR is acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this meaning of [**Conceive**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conceive)

> Form or devise (a plan or idea) in the mind.

*Oxford Dictionaries*

Basically, the sentence can be reworded as:

> The Consultant acknowledges that he will receive or **create/form new** confidential information pertaining to the activities

So, in your job role, you may be given confidential information, or you may be tasked to create new confidential information as part of your job. This is basically the Company informing you that some of the work you create will be considered confidential and cannot be shared outside of the relevant parties.